# Swift / Refactoring of element attributes

Tags: ios, swift

I have several elements of a UICollectionView with the following code:

```
    cell.eventsImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.eventsImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    cell.eventsImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
    cell.eventsImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.uIColorFromHex(0xE90289).CGColor
```

What's the best practise to refactor that?

I want to do something like:

```
    class refactoredXY (Bool, Double, Double, CGColor) {
        clipsToBounds = Bool
        cornerRadius = Double
        borderWidth = Double
        borderColor = CGColor 
    }
```

To call:

```
    cell.eventsImageView.refactoredXY(true, 10.0, 4.0, UIColor.uIColorFromHex(0xE90289))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're actually modifying UIImageView properties, you can go for [Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151), where you will add function, that do what you need. Like this

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setDesiredProperties(clipsToBounds clipToBounds : Bool, layerCornerRadius : CGFloat, layerBorderWidth : CGFloat, layerBorderColor : UIColor) {
        self.clipsToBounds = clipToBounds;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = layerCornerRadius;
        self.layer.borderWidth = layerBorderWidth;
        self.layer.borderColor = layerBorderColor.CGColor;
     }
}
```

Then you can simply call it like this

```
cell.eventsImageView.setDesiredProperties(true, 10.0, 4.0, UIColor.uIColorFromHex(0xE90289));
```

Also, if you you want this function be available only for you cells not all `UIImageView`s, you can make it this way

```
extension YourCollectionViewCellClass {
    func setDesiredProperties(clipsToBounds clipToBounds : Bool, layerCornerRadius : CGFloat, layerBorderWidth : CGFloat, layerBorderColor : UIColor) {
        self.eventsImageView.clipsToBounds = clipToBounds;
        self.eventsImageView.layer.cornerRadius = layerCornerRadius;
        self.eventsImageView.layer.borderWidth = layerBorderWidth;
        self.eventsImageView.layer.borderColor = layerBorderColor.CGColor;
     }
}
```

and apply it this way

```
cell.setDesiredProperties(true, 10.0, 4.0, UIColor.uIColorFromHex(0xE90289));
```

Comment: These inputs vars are wrongs: actually cornerRadius is not compatible with double, it's a CGFloat value, same thing for borderWidth.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Yes, missed that. Thanx for pointing that out

Comment: Thank you for the help and the great explanation.